# Can't get user info getting error like "unauthorized_client

Tags: python, django, keycloak

**Error: Description**

**KeycloakAuthenticationError** at 
401: b'{"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"Client certificate missing, or its thumbprint and one in the refresh token did NOT match"}'

Please refer my code get solution

```
                    # Configure client
    keycloak_openid = KeycloakOpenID(server_url="http://localhost:8080/auth/",
                        client_id="testclient1",
                        realm_name="Realm",
                        client_secret_key="******")
            token = keycloak_openid.token("kishore", "Kichakcb001@")
    print(token)        
            userinfo = keycloak_openid.userinfo(token['access_token'])
    print(userinfo)
```

Thanks,
Kishore

Answer (score 0):

Please, see this issue in Keycloak:

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-6771

And the documentation about "Mutual TLS Client Certificate Bound Access Tokens":

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-mtls-08#section-3

Comment: Thanks for answer, Finally i got the solution